# Using Pexpect for multiple kind of devices

Tags: python, pexpect

I am trying to access a device from a server using python script. I am using pexpect module for the same. The device may or may not have authentication. I have written the following code but it is not working as expected. Can anyone please help?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('telnet 10.xxx.xxx.xxx')
i = child.expect(['Username:','.*#'])
if i==0:
    child.sendline('user')
    child.expect('Password: ')
    child.sendline('password')

child.expect('.*#')
print "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be perfectly fine. I even tested it on my device and it works. Please check if you have made any other errors. If not, please mention the exact error you are getting while execution.

Comment: thank you..I had made some other errors due to which it was not properly functioning.